# How to prove the inductive step in this Mathematical induction problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

**Note:** This problem is from Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications [7th ed, prob 6, pg 342].

**Problem:**
a) Determine which amounts of postage can be formed using just $3$-cent and $10$-cent stamps.
b)Prove your answer to $(a)$ using the principle of mathematical induction. Be sure to state explicitly your inductive hypothesis in the inductive step

**My work:**
For part a, I was able to do this by writing out a pattern of amounts that can be formed with just $3$ cent and $10$ cent stamps $-0, 3, 6, 9, 10, 13, 16, 19, 20, \cdots $
From this pattern I determined that amounts of postage with digits that end with $0$, $3$, $6$, or $9$ can be formed using just $3$-cent and $10$-cent stamps.
For part b, My basis case was 0 and I showed that $0$ can be formed with $0$ $3$ cent stamps and $0$ $10$ cent stamps.
My inductive hypothesis was that for some integer $k$, $k \geq 0, k$ can be formed with just 3 cent and 10 cent stamps. 
What I am confused about is what to do for the inductive step. I know that the inductive step is to show $P(k) \Rightarrow P(k + 1)$ but for this problem, $k + 1$ isn't necessarily going to be able to be formed by just $3$ cent and $10$ cent stamps, say 4 for instance.
Is there another way I can represent $k + 1$? The way I have it set up is 
$\quad k = 3 a + 10b$ where $a$ and $b$ are some integer $\geq 0$
$\quad k + 1 = 3a + 10b + 1$

but then $k + 1$ isn't necessarily a linear combination of $3$ and $10$.....

Comment: P(3n) -> P(3(n+1))

Comment: Check out [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ericp/teaching/Fall2013/55/hwk7.pdf) link which has an answer/proof for this exact question. Also, *please* typeset your questions correctly (I see you still refuse to learn how to correctly use $\LaTeX$ / MathJax).

Comment: what about 12, 15, 18, etc...

Comment: @crash Wait what? I typed out the question, did the thing for P(k), P(k+1). TB12

Comment: You can actually make a stronger hypothesis than that. Particularly, you can make a hypothesis about all postage amounts greater than 17. Hint: there are a few possibilities you missed in your pattern.

Comment: The *layout* is fine in terms of its structure, but, just as in your comment above, it should be $P(k), P(k+1)$, etc.

Comment: @crash I did add dollar signs around that

Comment: How about for "k = 3 a + 10b where a and b are some integer >= 0"? This *should* appear as follows: $k=3a+10b$ where $a$ and $b$ are some integer $\geq 0$.

Comment: 3m+10n, where n, m are non negative integers.

Comment: The known theorem about this is the fact that given $a$ and $b$ such that $gcd(a,b)=1$ all numbers greater then $ab-a-b$ can be written as $ax+by$ for some $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The following is obvious without a formal induction proof:

Starting with $0$ we can do all multiples of $3$, starting with $10$ we can do all numbers of the form $3k+1$ as well, and starting with $20$ we can do all numbers of the form $3k+2$ as well.